# Checking if notifications are enabled - Windows phone 8(.1)

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

Short question this time - is it possible for me to check whether the user has disabled notifications in the notifications/actions centre?

Currently, notifications are sent via MPNS, and work as intended, and the only "issue" is being aware if the user will receive toast notifications or not :)

The only two sources I managed to find so far even remotely connected are the one discussing [possible restrictions due to the battery saver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202940(v=vs.105).aspx), and discussing [sending toast notifications from application](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WindowsPhone-81-Action-4fef1501) (which is not what is needed here).

Since MS states in [their documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465391.aspx) that we're not supposed to "use your app to ask users to enable toast notifications if they have chosen to disable them. Your app is expected to work without toast notifications.", I feel that perhaps this information is not as freely accessible as it might seem at first glance, but hopefully some of you can either confirm my suspicions or help me overcome it :)